# Oracle 11g Rotate Result Table 90 Degrees

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, unpivot

I need to rotate a result set by 90 degrees.  I've been playing with pivot and unpivot but haven't managed to get anything to work thus far.  The result set looks like this:

```
2018-07-03  TUE 20:00   12:15   465 (null)
2018-07-02  MON 20:00   20:05   -5  FAIL
2018-06-29  FRI 19:30   19:04   26  (null)
2018-06-28  THU 20:00   19:07   53  (null)
2018-06-27  WED 20:00   19:37   23  (null)
```

What I need is to be able to rotate the entire result set by 90 degrees so that column 1 (the dates) become the column headers and the reset of the data falls underneath those columns, like this:

```
2018-06-27  2018-06-28  2018-06-29  2018-07-02  2018-07-03
WED         THU         FRI         MON         TUE
20:00       20:00       19:30       20:00       20:00
19:37       19:07       19:04       20:05       12:15
23          53          56          -5          465
(null)      (null)      (null)      FAIL        (null)
```

Is there another function that makes this possible, or perhaps a pivot/unpivot method that I haven't figured out?

Comment: Each column now contains different types of data in it, you'll need a column for each row in the result set. For what system would consuming data in such a manner be an advantage?

Answer (score 0):

You may generate such a logic as using this SQL

```
select vl as date1, myCol as myCol1
    from 
       (
        select to_char(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') as mD, 
               to_char(myDate,'DY') as Dy, 
               to_char(myVal) as mVl, t.* from tab t
         where to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = <a_date_parameter>
       )
        unpivot (vl for myCol in (mD,Dy,myHourStart, myHourEnd,mVl,status))
```

by the contribution of `unpivot` concept as :

```
create table tab( myDate date, myHourStart varchar2(5), myHourEnd varchar2(5), myVal int, status varchar2(15) );
insert all 
   into tab values( date'2018-07-03','20:00','12:15', 465, null )
   into tab values( date'2018-07-02','20:00','20:05', -5, 'FAIL' )
   into tab values( date'2018-06-29','19:30','19:04', 26,  null )
   into tab values( date'2018-06-28','20:00','19:07', 53, null )
   into tab values( date'2018-06-27','20:00','19:37', 23,  null ) 
select * from dual;

select date1, date2, date3, date4, date5 from
(  select vl as date1, myCol as myCol1
    from 
       (
        select to_char(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') as mD, 
               to_char(myDate,'DY') as Dy, 
               to_char(myVal) as mVl, t.* from tab t
         where to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2018-06-27'
       )
        unpivot (vl for myCol in (mD,Dy,myHourStart, myHourEnd,mVl,status)) 
         ) q1 join
  (  select vl as date2, myCol as myCol2
      from 
         (
          select to_char(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') as mD, 
                 to_char(myDate,'DY') as Dy,
                 to_char(myVal) as mVl, t.* from tab t
           where to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2018-06-28'
         )
          unpivot (vl for myCol in (mD,Dy,myHourStart, myHourEnd,mVl,status)) 
           ) q2 on ( q1.myCol1 = q2.myCol2  )  
join
  (  select vl as date3, myCol as myCol3
      from 
         (
          select to_char(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') as mD, 
                 to_char(myDate,'DY') as Dy,
                 to_char(myVal) as mVl, t.* from tab t
           where to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2018-06-29'
         )
          unpivot (vl for myCol in (mD,Dy,myHourStart, myHourEnd,mVl,status)) 
           ) q3 on ( q1.myCol1 = q3.myCol3  ) 
join
  (  select vl as date4, myCol as myCol4
      from 
         (
          select to_char(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') as mD, 
                 to_char(myDate,'DY') as Dy,
                 to_char(myVal) as mVl, t.* from tab t
           where to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2018-07-02'
         )
          unpivot (vl for myCol in (mD,Dy,myHourStart, myHourEnd,mVl,status)) 
           ) q4 on ( q1.myCol1 = q4.myCol4  )            
join
  (  select vl as date5, myCol as myCol5
      from 
         (
          select to_char(myDate,'yyyy-mm-dd') as mD, 
                 to_char(myDate,'DY') as Dy,
                 to_char(myVal) as mVl, t.* from tab t
           where to_char(mydate,'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2018-07-03'
         )
          unpivot (vl for myCol in (mD,Dy,myHourStart, myHourEnd,mVl,status)) 
           ) q5 on ( q1.myCol1 = q5.myCol5  );
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59b93/64)